# rails Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe

am making code mirror in rails but the iframe is not displaying and it caugh error. the code works fine in normal html page but fails on ruby on rails  this error

```
new:269 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null
```

and this the line it happens
`iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;`

and this my whole new code

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

  <div class="row">

  <!-- Code Editors -->
  <div class="col s6">
    <div class="row">
      <%= form_for(@hcj) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="field">
        <div id="html" class="s3">
          <h3>HTML</h3>

          <%= f.text_area :html, placeholder: "Compose new micropost...", name: "html" %>
        </div>

        <div id="css" class="s3">
          <h3>css</h3>
          <%= f.text_area :css, placeholder: "Compose new micropost...", name: "css" %>
        </div>
        <div id="js" class="s3">
          <h3>js</h3>
          <%= f.text_area :js, placeholder: "Compose new micropost...", name: "js" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>


  </div>

  <!-- Sandboxing -->
  <h3>sandbox</h3>
  <div class="col s6">
    <iframe id="frameId"></iframe>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var frame = window.frames.frameId;
  </script>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
    (function () {

        // Base template
        var base_tpl =
            "<!doctype html>\n" +
            "<html>\n\t" +
            "<head>\n\t\t" +
            "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\t\t" +
            "<title>Test</title>\n\n\t\t\n\t" +
            "</head>\n\t" +
            "<body>\n\t\n\t" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>";

        var prepareSource = function () {
            var html = html_editor.getValue(),
                css = css_editor.getValue(),
                js = js_editor.getValue(),
                src = '';

            // HTML
            src = base_tpl.replace('</body>', html + '</body>');

            // CSS
            css = '<style>' + css + '</style>';
            src = src.replace('</head>', css + '</head>');

            // Javascript
            js = '<script>' + js + '<\/script>';
            src = src.replace('</body>', js + '</body>');

            return src;
        };

        var render = function () {
            var source = prepareSource();

            var iframe = document.querySelector('#output iframe'),
                iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;

            iframe_doc.open();
            iframe_doc.write(source);
            iframe_doc.close();
        };


        // EDITORS

        // CM OPTIONS
        var cm_opt = {
            mode: 'text/html',
            gutter: true,
            lineNumbers: true,
        };

        // HTML EDITOR
        var html_box = document.querySelector('#html textarea');
        var html_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(html_box, cm_opt);

        html_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
            render();
        });

        // CSS EDITOR
        cm_opt.mode = 'css';
        var css_box = document.querySelector('#css textarea');
        var css_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(css_box, cm_opt);

        css_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
            render();
        });

        // JAVASCRIPT EDITOR
        cm_opt.mode = 'javascript';
        var js_box = document.querySelector('#js textarea');
        var js_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(js_box, cm_opt);

        js_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
            render();
        });

        // SETTING CODE EDITORS INITIAL CONTENT
        html_editor.setValue('<p>Hello World</p>');
        css_editor.setValue('body { color: red; }');


        // RENDER CALL ON PAGE LOAD
        // NOT NEEDED ANYMORE, SINCE WE RELY
        // ON CODEMIRROR'S onChange OPTION THAT GETS
        // TRIGGERED ON setValue
        // render();


        // NOT SO IMPORTANT - IF YOU NEED TO DO THIS
        // THEN THIS SHOULD GO TO CSS

        /*
          Fixing the Height of CodeMirror.
          You might want to do this in CSS instead
          of JS and override the styles from the main
          codemirror.css
        */
        var cms = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror');
        for (var i = 0; i < cms.length; i++) {

            cms[i].style.position = 'absolute';
            cms[i].style.top = '30px';
            cms[i].style.bottom = '0';
            cms[i].style.left = '0';
            cms[i].style.right = '0';
            cms[i].style.height = '100%';
        }
        /*cms = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror-scroll');
        for (i = 0; i < cms.length; i++) {
          cms[i].style.height = '100%';
        }*/

    }());
</script>
```

Comment: What does `i am making code mirror in rails but i et this error` mean? Please take the time to revise the problem description so it is more understandable.

Comment: have revise my question

Answer (score 0):

Set `id` for your iframe and then you can get your frame by this code:

```
<iframe id="frameId"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frame = window.frames.frameId;
</script>
```

Comment: this works fine in normal html but fails on ruby on rails

Comment: Are you sure that your `iframe` exists in your html-code after it is rendered by ruby on rails?

Comment: yes it is and shows this in the debugger section var iframe = document.querySelector('#output iframe'),
  iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument; @Dmitriy and also trows out this error when ever i change anything in the textareas                                         Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null

Comment: type `document.querySelector('#output iframe')` in your console(F12). What is the result? `null` or `iframe`?

Comment: It means that there is no iframe inside element with id `output`. Or this iframe is inside another frame.

Comment: what was the reason? frame inside frame? :)

Comment: i did not give and ID of output to a element